# ORACLE SQL - how to manipulate single column without selecting it

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I manipulate a single column without actually "selecting" it specifically?
So, lets say I have a table with columns A, B , C, D, ... and I want to multiply column C by 2, but want to get all columns as output without having to "select" them all, so I would like to use select *.

So, instead of

```
SELECT A, B, 2*C, D, E, F, ..... FROM T
```

I would like to

```
SELECT * FROM T [do something here to multiply C by 2]
```

How could I do that?

Comment: Why? It's hardly ever a good idea to `select *`.

Comment: You say "manipulate", but you do not mean updating the column in the database, right? You basically want something like `SELECT * BUT NOT C2, 2*C2 FROM T`?

Comment: @San You still have to list all columns separately in the view's select, since you can not drop individual columns from the view after creating a view like `as select * from ...`, right?

Comment: @Andreas Yes, you are right, but the purpose will be fulfilled, OP can write `select * from V` (say V is view name) any where he wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
SELECT 2*C AS DOUBLE_C, T.* FROM T
```

You'll still get C as well, but it will be one single `SELECT` statement.